# classification of web-applications in web 2.0

Tags: web-applications, classification

How can i classify web-applications broadly in general in web 2.0 ? What are the types of web-applications and how can i categorize them?

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: by version number (web 1.0, web 2.0, etc. :)

Comment: @Josef added the version number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas by me:

- interactive (using ajax) / non interactive
- is it an enterprise web-application -> how many tiers are used / is a database necessary
- maybe which programming language is used -> c# web-app / java web-app

...

Answer (score 3):

There are many dimensions to consider, here's a few:

1. Information v Action - does the user read info or do they make changes to content?
2. Is money involved? Recording the results of a survery v buying a product or service
3. Internet v Intranet? Impacts the different browsers we need to support, intranet you may be able to demand only certain browsers
4. Web 2.0? Do we see ajax calls and lots of JavaScript
5. Media content? Is streaming video or some such important
6. Volume: how many simultaneous users and what request frequency? Greatly affects your server-side architecture and design.
7. Importance: if it's business critical then again you need to pay a lot of attention to robustness of application and infrastructure. Loss of service on some web sites may have a very bad commercial impact.
8. Importance of support or mobile devices: support for such devices is increasingly important and adds a whole new dimension of complexity for the developer.

Comment: can i classify them as static web applications and dynamic web applications, where static web applications only have static html pages and dynamic web applications have client side scripting, server side scripting or both

Comment: Yes, that's a valid classification too. I was trying to illustrate that there are many different ways of classifying, and they will lead to quite major differences in approach.